# Foundation Panini how to add a manifest.json file to my dist folder in build process

Tags: zurb-foundation, progressive-web-apps, zurb-foundation-6, manifest.json

I've just learned how to build my website using the Foundation Panini library using Foundation CLI. I've successfully finished building all the pages and it works great, but I cannot figure out how to add my manifest.json file at the root (to my dist folder). I need to add manifest.json and browserconfig.xml files to my dist folder that will go in the root directory. Also a favicon.ico file. How can you get those included in the build process. Right now they are saved in my src folder.

I'm a total beginner at this, so any help would be much appreciated. I think I probably need to add something to the gulp.babel.js file, but I'm just not sure how to do it and I have searched and searched online and cannot find anything on how to do that. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords in my search.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a folder or file in the assets folder. The copy function in the gulpFile controls what gets transferred to dist.

```
function copy() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.assets).pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets'));
}
```

Comment: Ok so I added those files to the assets folder, but then they just stay in the assets folder in dist in the build. I need them to be in the "root" of the dist folder.